# Components to navigate to another page with React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

is it proper to write components like this? I want to redirect user to another page after click on button in my menu? What should i change here? Maybe use Link instead of button?

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import './MyAccountButton.scss';

const MyAccountButton = ({ path }) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleButtonClick = () => {
    history.push(path);
  };

  return (
    <div className="my-account-button">
      <button type="button" onClick={() => handleButtonClick()}>
        My account
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyAccountButton;
```

PS. Any advices how to unit test this component with jest and enzyme??

Comment: Why not directly use the Link component and style it as a button?

Comment: @ChrisR it would be more correct?

Comment: Using a Link you wouldn't have to manually push a new item to history and that's exactly what you want to achieve, click on something to access a new path, no?